# How to extract date from file as a string?

Tags: python, file, datetime

I'm having issues. This is my first time using datetime and I would like some help.
date_str is the input then I convert it to a date format strptime
date is the date extracted from the file, which is usually in this format (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
def read_file(filename):
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
   sheet = wb.active
   data = []


   for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
       data.append(row)

   return data

def main():
   filename = input("Enter file name: ")
   data = read_file(filename)

   date_str = input("Enter date YYYY-MM-DD: ")
   new_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

   for date in data:
      if date == new_date:
          print(f"Date: {date}")
```

The if statement doesn't work because they don't match. date is datetime.datetime and new_date is datetime.date. Can someone please help me understand how to make it so that the if statement works? Also, is there a way so that it doesn't return with the time (min, hrs, etc)?

Update:

Okay, I got it. I just left the user input as str and didn't convert it to datetime. Then I took date and convert it to an str, `date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. Now it's working!

Comment: What is `number`? What is `data`?

Comment: `new_date` is a `date` object. If `data` is a file, `date` is a string. They won't be equal, you need to parse `date`.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to include that part. I just updated the code.
I have tried to do this but you can see that this is not correct  
datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: Please share your import, what do you expect where is your data list? What should be number? Please improve your code for a minimal working example, what shows us your problem.

Comment: `data` is a list of tuples, the tuples have values for each column. You need to index them to get the date column.

Comment: Your `if` is always FALSE, because you compare a `<class 'str'> ` with a `<class 'datetime.date'> ` as @Barmar told you.

Comment: I got the fix, I added the answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead, I left the user input as str and didn't convert it to datetime. Then I took date and convert it to an str, `date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example, how you can convert your string to a datetime.date object:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

d_in = input("Enter your date yyyy, mm, dd : ")
new_date = datetime.strptime(d_in, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

# input str from your file read "2023-08-22" convert to datetime.date
d = date.fromisoformat('2023-08-22')
print(d)
print(type(d))
             
if d == new_date:
    print('If loop works now')
```